# How to find the title of a element in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

```html
<div>

  <div class="alk_dvImage"><a href="/products/"><img class="alk_prImg" src="https://a random photo" alt="a random product"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="product-score"></div>
  

  <a href="/products/" class="alk_prName alk_pr" title="Products Title">Strong Graphic Card
  </a>

</div>
```

Lets assume we have a html as given above. I want to extract the title of the 'a' element which is nested in a div. And also i want the class of this same element how ever when i try this code

`browser.find_element_by_css_selector('a.alk_prName alk_pr')`

this does not  respond anything. Btw i couldnt do anything to get tite of a element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### What happens?

Your not chaining the classes by dot in your selector, try the following:

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('a.alk_prName.alk_pr').get_attribute("title")
```

**Example:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Program Files\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')

html_content = """
  <a href="/products/" class="alk_prName alk_pr" title="Products Title">Strong Graphic Card</a>
"""

browser.get("data:text/html;charset=utf-8,{html_content}".format(html_content=html_content))

browser.find_element_by_css_selector('a.alk_prName.alk_pr').get_attribute("title")
```

Comment: Why did you use `html_content = <a href="/products/" class="alk_prName alk_pr" title="Products Title">Strong Graphic Card</a>` this is not whole html script. By the way i get the title thanks to you.

Answer (score 1):

To print the value of the *title* attribute i.e. **Products Title** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.alk_prName.alk_pr[href='/products/']").get_attribute("title"))
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@class='alk_prName alk_pr' and @href='/products/'][contains(., 'Strong Graphic Card')]").get_attribute("title"))
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.alk_prName.alk_pr[href='/products/']"))).get_attribute("value"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='alk_prName alk_pr' and @href='/products/'][contains(., 'Strong Graphic Card')]"))).get_attribute("value"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: How can i find more than one element by using `(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.alk_prName.alk_pr[href='/products/']"))).get_attribute("value") ` this method. I need every element in the page where classes equals a.alk_prName.alk_p. How ever this returns me only one element.

Comment: @omneer Of coarse this question title reads as _title of a element_, for more than one element feel free to raise a new ticket.